# How to export a tikzpicture to svg with text tags?

Tags: svg, export, dvisvgm

### Premise

I don't know if this was already asked but I searched for it and only found something relevant but nothing that solved my problem. Probably the most related question is [How to create non-outlined SVG files from LaTeX formulae?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282340/how-to-create-non-outlined-svg-files-from-latex-formulae/282594)

### What I'm aiming for

I want to produce same content in LaTeX and then include it in my static website. The content should be a standalone tikzpicture with some text in it. The text could be plain text or math text. The text should be rendered accordly to the text in the web page (font family, size and so on).

### My idea

I would like to use svg images because they are vectorial and support text tag. In this case the plain text should be rendered normally based on the CSS while the math should be saved as LaTeX unprocessed commands in the svg and then pre-processed through KaTeX. Let's handle the simple case first: the plain text. I tried to compile something like this `test.tex` file

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex test.tex` and convert it with `pdf2svg test.pdf test.svg` but I didn't obtained any text tag (the text was rendered as vectorial). The same happened compiling it with `latex test.tex` and converting it with `dvisvgm -n test.dvi`.

So the question is: how could I export an svg image with text inside?

### Edit: complete example with dvisvgm

This is my `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
  \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
  \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
  %\tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
  \tikzstyle{input}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
  \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
  \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
  \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

  % Draw the input layer nodes
  \node[input] (L0-1) at (0,-1) {$x_1$};
  \node[input] (L0-2) at (0,-2) {$x_2$};
  \node[input] (L0-3) at (0,-3) {$x_n$};

  % Draw the output layer node
  \node[output neuron] (L1-1) at (\layersep, -2) {$\hat{y}$};

  % Connect every node in the input layer with the output layer
  \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
    \path (L0-\source) edge (L1-1);

  % Annotate the layers
  \node[annot,above of=L0-1, node distance=1cm] (il) {layer 0};
  \node[annot,right of=il] {layer 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

Then I run:

```
latex test.tex
dvisvgm -n test.dvi
```

and this is my `test.svg`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 2.1.3 -->
<svg height='97.9372pt' version='1.1' viewBox='-59.976 -68.6794 99.9521 97.9372' width='99.9521pt' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
<defs>
<path d='M3.32752 -3.00872C3.3873 -3.26775 3.61644 -4.18431 4.31382 -4.18431C4.36364 -4.18431 4.60274 -4.18431 4.81196 -4.05479C4.533 -4.00498 4.33375 -3.75592 4.33375 -3.51681C4.33375 -3.35741 4.44334 -3.16812 4.71233 -3.16812C4.93151 -3.16812 5.25031 -3.34745 5.25031 -3.74595C5.25031 -4.26401 4.66252 -4.40349 4.32379 -4.40349C3.74595 -4.40349 3.39726 -3.87547 3.27771 -3.64633C3.02864 -4.30386 2.49066 -4.40349 2.20174 -4.40349C1.16563 -4.40349 0.597758 -3.11831 0.597758 -2.86924C0.597758 -2.76961 0.697385 -2.76961 0.71731 -2.76961C0.797011 -2.76961 0.826899 -2.78954 0.846824 -2.8792C1.18555 -3.93524 1.84309 -4.18431 2.18182 -4.18431C2.37111 -4.18431 2.7198 -4.09465 2.7198 -3.51681C2.7198 -3.20797 2.55044 -2.54047 2.18182 -1.1457C2.02242 -0.52802 1.67372 -0.109589 1.23537 -0.109589C1.17559 -0.109589 0.946451 -0.109589 0.737235 -0.239103C0.986301 -0.288917 1.20548 -0.498132 1.20548 -0.777086C1.20548 -1.04608 0.986301 -1.12578 0.836862 -1.12578C0.537983 -1.12578 0.288917 -0.86675 0.288917 -0.547945C0.288917 -0.0896638 0.787049 0.109589 1.2254 0.109589C1.88294 0.109589 2.24159 -0.587796 2.27148 -0.647572C2.39103 -0.278954 2.74969 0.109589 3.34745 0.109589C4.3736 0.109589 4.94147 -1.17559 4.94147 -1.42466C4.94147 -1.52428 4.85181 -1.52428 4.82192 -1.52428C4.73225 -1.52428 4.71233 -1.48443 4.6924 -1.41469C4.36364 -0.348692 3.68618 -0.109589 3.36737 -0.109589C2.97883 -0.109589 2.81943 -0.428394 2.81943 -0.767123C2.81943 -0.986301 2.8792 -1.20548 2.98879 -1.64384L3.32752 -3.00872Z' id='g0-120'/>
<path d='M4.84184 -3.79577C4.88169 -3.93524 4.88169 -3.95517 4.88169 -4.02491C4.88169 -4.20423 4.74222 -4.2939 4.59278 -4.2939C4.49315 -4.2939 4.33375 -4.23412 4.24408 -4.08468C4.22416 -4.03487 4.14446 -3.72603 4.10461 -3.5467C4.03487 -3.28767 3.96513 -3.01868 3.90535 -2.74969L3.45704 -0.956413C3.41719 -0.806974 2.98879 -0.109589 2.33126 -0.109589C1.82316 -0.109589 1.71357 -0.547945 1.71357 -0.916563C1.71357 -1.37484 1.88294 -1.99253 2.22167 -2.86924C2.38107 -3.27771 2.42092 -3.3873 2.42092 -3.58655C2.42092 -4.03487 2.10212 -4.40349 1.60399 -4.40349C0.657534 -4.40349 0.288917 -2.9589 0.288917 -2.86924C0.288917 -2.76961 0.388543 -2.76961 0.408468 -2.76961C0.508095 -2.76961 0.518057 -2.78954 0.56787 -2.94894C0.836862 -3.88543 1.23537 -4.18431 1.5741 -4.18431C1.6538 -4.18431 1.82316 -4.18431 1.82316 -3.8655C1.82316 -3.61644 1.72354 -3.35741 1.6538 -3.16812C1.25529 -2.11208 1.07597 -1.54421 1.07597 -1.07597C1.07597 -0.18929 1.70361 0.109589 2.29141 0.109589C2.67995 0.109589 3.01868 -0.0597758 3.29763 -0.33873C3.16812 0.179328 3.04857 0.667497 2.65006 1.19552C2.39103 1.53425 2.01245 1.82316 1.55417 1.82316C1.41469 1.82316 0.966376 1.79328 0.797011 1.40473C0.956413 1.40473 1.08593 1.40473 1.2254 1.28518C1.32503 1.19552 1.42466 1.066 1.42466 0.876712C1.42466 0.56787 1.15567 0.52802 1.05604 0.52802C0.826899 0.52802 0.498132 0.687422 0.498132 1.17559C0.498132 1.67372 0.936488 2.04234 1.55417 2.04234C2.58032 2.04234 3.60648 1.13574 3.88543 0.00996264L4.84184 -3.79577Z' id='g0-121'/>
<path d='M4.58281 -3.18804C4.58281 -3.98506 4.533 -4.78207 4.18431 -5.5193C3.72603 -6.47572 2.90909 -6.63512 2.49066 -6.63512C1.8929 -6.63512 1.16563 -6.37609 0.757161 -5.44956C0.438356 -4.76214 0.388543 -3.98506 0.388543 -3.18804C0.388543 -2.44085 0.428394 -1.54421 0.836862 -0.787049C1.26526 0.0199253 1.99253 0.219178 2.4807 0.219178C3.01868 0.219178 3.77584 0.00996264 4.2142 -0.936488C4.533 -1.62391 4.58281 -2.401 4.58281 -3.18804ZM2.4807 0C2.09215 0 1.50436 -0.249066 1.32503 -1.20548C1.21544 -1.80324 1.21544 -2.7198 1.21544 -3.3076C1.21544 -3.94521 1.21544 -4.60274 1.29514 -5.14072C1.48443 -6.32628 2.23163 -6.41594 2.4807 -6.41594C2.80946 -6.41594 3.467 -6.23661 3.65629 -5.25031C3.75592 -4.6924 3.75592 -3.93524 3.75592 -3.3076C3.75592 -2.5604 3.75592 -1.88294 3.64633 -1.24533C3.49689 -0.298879 2.92902 0 2.4807 0Z' id='g2-48'/>
<path d='M2.92902 -6.37609C2.92902 -6.61519 2.92902 -6.63512 2.69988 -6.63512C2.08219 -5.99751 1.20548 -5.99751 0.886675 -5.99751V-5.68867C1.08593 -5.68867 1.67372 -5.68867 2.19178 -5.9477V-0.787049C2.19178 -0.428394 2.16189 -0.308842 1.26526 -0.308842H0.946451V0C1.29514 -0.0298879 2.16189 -0.0298879 2.5604 -0.0298879S3.82565 -0.0298879 4.17435 0V-0.308842H3.85554C2.9589 -0.308842 2.92902 -0.418431 2.92902 -0.787049V-6.37609Z' id='g2-49'/>
<path d='M2.49066 -6.91407L1.15567 -5.55915L1.33499 -5.37983L2.49066 -6.39601L3.63636 -5.37983L3.81569 -5.55915L2.49066 -6.91407Z' id='g2-94'/>
<path d='M3.31756 -0.757161C3.35741 -0.358655 3.6264 0.0597758 4.09465 0.0597758C4.30386 0.0597758 4.91158 -0.0797011 4.91158 -0.886675V-1.44458H4.66252V-0.886675C4.66252 -0.308842 4.41345 -0.249066 4.30386 -0.249066C3.97509 -0.249066 3.93524 -0.697385 3.93524 -0.747198V-2.73973C3.93524 -3.15816 3.93524 -3.5467 3.57659 -3.91532C3.18804 -4.30386 2.68991 -4.46326 2.21171 -4.46326C1.39477 -4.46326 0.707347 -3.99502 0.707347 -3.33748C0.707347 -3.03861 0.9066 -2.86924 1.16563 -2.86924C1.44458 -2.86924 1.62391 -3.06849 1.62391 -3.32752C1.62391 -3.44707 1.5741 -3.77584 1.11582 -3.7858C1.38481 -4.1345 1.87298 -4.24408 2.19178 -4.24408C2.67995 -4.24408 3.24782 -3.85554 3.24782 -2.96887V-2.60025C2.73973 -2.57036 2.04234 -2.54047 1.41469 -2.24159C0.667497 -1.90286 0.418431 -1.38481 0.418431 -0.946451C0.418431 -0.139477 1.38481 0.109589 2.01245 0.109589C2.66999 0.109589 3.12827 -0.288917 3.31756 -0.757161ZM3.24782 -2.39103V-1.39477C3.24782 -0.448319 2.53051 -0.109589 2.08219 -0.109589C1.59402 -0.109589 1.18555 -0.458281 1.18555 -0.956413C1.18555 -1.50436 1.60399 -2.33126 3.24782 -2.39103Z' id='g2-97'/>
<path d='M1.11582 -2.51059C1.17559 -3.99502 2.01245 -4.24408 2.35118 -4.24408C3.37733 -4.24408 3.47696 -2.89913 3.47696 -2.51059H1.11582ZM1.10585 -2.30137H3.88543C4.10461 -2.30137 4.1345 -2.30137 4.1345 -2.51059C4.1345 -3.49689 3.59651 -4.46326 2.35118 -4.46326C1.19552 -4.46326 0.278954 -3.43711 0.278954 -2.19178C0.278954 -0.856787 1.32503 0.109589 2.47073 0.109589C3.68618 0.109589 4.1345 -0.996264 4.1345 -1.18555C4.1345 -1.28518 4.05479 -1.30511 4.00498 -1.30511C3.91532 -1.30511 3.89539 -1.24533 3.87547 -1.16563C3.52677 -0.139477 2.63014 -0.139477 2.53051 -0.139477C2.03238 -0.139477 1.63387 -0.438356 1.40473 -0.806974C1.10585 -1.28518 1.10585 -1.94271 1.10585 -2.30137Z' id='g2-101'/>
<path d='M1.76339 -6.91407L0.328767 -6.80448V-6.49564C1.02615 -6.49564 1.10585 -6.4259 1.10585 -5.93773V-0.757161C1.10585 -0.308842 0.996264 -0.308842 0.328767 -0.308842V0C0.657534 -0.00996264 1.18555 -0.0298879 1.43462 -0.0298879S2.17186 -0.00996264 2.54047 0V-0.308842C1.87298 -0.308842 1.76339 -0.308842 1.76339 -0.757161V-6.91407Z' id='g2-108'/>
<path d='M1.66376 -3.3076V-4.40349L0.278954 -4.2939V-3.98506C0.976339 -3.98506 1.05604 -3.91532 1.05604 -3.42715V-0.757161C1.05604 -0.308842 0.946451 -0.308842 0.278954 -0.308842V0C0.667497 -0.00996264 1.13574 -0.0298879 1.41469 -0.0298879C1.8132 -0.0298879 2.28144 -0.0298879 2.67995 0V-0.308842H2.47073C1.7335 -0.308842 1.71357 -0.418431 1.71357 -0.777086V-2.31133C1.71357 -3.29763 2.132 -4.18431 2.88917 -4.18431C2.9589 -4.18431 2.97883 -4.18431 2.99875 -4.17435C2.96887 -4.16438 2.76961 -4.04483 2.76961 -3.7858C2.76961 -3.50685 2.97883 -3.35741 3.19801 -3.35741C3.37733 -3.35741 3.6264 -3.47696 3.6264 -3.79577S3.31756 -4.40349 2.88917 -4.40349C2.16189 -4.40349 1.80324 -3.73599 1.66376 -3.3076Z' id='g2-114'/>
<path d='M4.1345 -3.34745C4.39352 -3.97509 4.90162 -3.98506 5.06102 -3.98506V-4.2939C4.83188 -4.27397 4.54296 -4.26401 4.31382 -4.26401C4.1345 -4.26401 3.66625 -4.28394 3.44707 -4.2939V-3.98506C3.75592 -3.97509 3.91532 -3.80573 3.91532 -3.55666C3.91532 -3.45704 3.90535 -3.43711 3.85554 -3.31756L2.84932 -0.86675L1.74346 -3.5467C1.70361 -3.64633 1.68369 -3.68618 1.68369 -3.72603C1.68369 -3.98506 2.0523 -3.98506 2.24159 -3.98506V-4.2939C1.98257 -4.28394 1.32503 -4.26401 1.15567 -4.26401C0.886675 -4.26401 0.488169 -4.27397 0.18929 -4.2939V-3.98506C0.667497 -3.98506 0.856787 -3.98506 0.996264 -3.63636L2.49066 0C2.44085 0.129514 2.30137 0.458281 2.24159 0.587796C2.02242 1.13574 1.74346 1.82316 1.10585 1.82316C1.05604 1.82316 0.826899 1.82316 0.637609 1.64384C0.946451 1.60399 1.02615 1.38481 1.02615 1.2254C1.02615 0.966376 0.836862 0.806974 0.607721 0.806974C0.408468 0.806974 0.18929 0.936488 0.18929 1.23537C0.18929 1.68369 0.607721 2.04234 1.10585 2.04234C1.7335 2.04234 2.14197 1.47447 2.38107 0.9066L4.1345 -3.34745Z' id='g2-121'/>
<path d='M0.850809 -0.439352C0.822914 -0.348692 0.781071 -0.174346 0.781071 -0.153425C0.781071 0 0.9066 0.0697385 1.01818 0.0697385C1.14371 0.0697385 1.25529 -0.0209215 1.29016 -0.0836862S1.38082 -0.369614 1.41569 -0.516065C1.45056 -0.648568 1.52727 -0.969365 1.56912 -1.14371C1.61096 -1.29714 1.6528 -1.45056 1.68767 -1.61096C1.76438 -1.89689 1.77833 -1.95268 1.98057 -2.23861C2.17584 -2.51756 2.50361 -2.8802 3.02665 -2.8802C3.43113 -2.8802 3.43811 -2.52453 3.43811 -2.39203C3.43811 -1.9736 3.13823 -1.1995 3.02665 -0.9066C2.94994 -0.711333 2.92204 -0.648568 2.92204 -0.530012C2.92204 -0.160399 3.22889 0.0697385 3.58456 0.0697385C4.28194 0.0697385 4.58879 -0.892653 4.58879 -0.99726C4.58879 -1.08792 4.49813 -1.08792 4.47721 -1.08792C4.37958 -1.08792 4.3726 -1.04608 4.34471 -0.969365C4.18431 -0.411457 3.88443 -0.125529 3.60548 -0.125529C3.45903 -0.125529 3.43113 -0.223163 3.43113 -0.369614C3.43113 -0.530012 3.466 -0.620672 3.59153 -0.934496C3.67522 -1.15068 3.96115 -1.88991 3.96115 -2.28045C3.96115 -2.95691 3.42416 -3.07547 3.05455 -3.07547C2.47572 -3.07547 2.08518 -2.7198 1.87597 -2.44085C1.82715 -2.92204 1.41569 -3.07547 1.12976 -3.07547C0.829888 -3.07547 0.669489 -2.85928 0.578829 -2.69888C0.425405 -2.44085 0.327771 -2.04334 0.327771 -2.00847C0.327771 -1.91781 0.425405 -1.91781 0.446326 -1.91781C0.54396 -1.91781 0.550934 -1.93873 0.599751 -2.12702C0.704359 -2.53848 0.836862 -2.8802 1.10884 -2.8802C1.29016 -2.8802 1.33898 -2.72677 1.33898 -2.53848C1.33898 -2.40598 1.27621 -2.14795 1.2274 -1.95965S1.10884 -1.48543 1.07397 -1.332L0.850809 -0.439352Z' id='g1-110'/>
<path d='M2.33624 -4.43537C2.33624 -4.62366 2.32229 -4.63064 2.12702 -4.63064C1.6807 -4.19128 1.04608 -4.18431 0.760149 -4.18431V-3.93325C0.927522 -3.93325 1.3878 -3.93325 1.77136 -4.12852V-0.571856C1.77136 -0.341719 1.77136 -0.251059 1.07397 -0.251059H0.808966V0C0.934496 -0.00697385 1.79228 -0.0278954 2.05031 -0.0278954C2.2665 -0.0278954 3.14521 -0.00697385 3.29863 0V-0.251059H3.03362C2.33624 -0.251059 2.33624 -0.341719 2.33624 -0.571856V-4.43537Z' id='g3-49'/>
<path d='M3.52179 -1.26924H3.28468C3.26376 -1.11582 3.19402 -0.704359 3.10336 -0.63462C3.04757 -0.592777 2.51059 -0.592777 2.41295 -0.592777H1.12976C1.86202 -1.24134 2.1061 -1.43661 2.52453 -1.76438C3.0406 -2.17584 3.52179 -2.60822 3.52179 -3.27073C3.52179 -4.11457 2.78257 -4.63064 1.88991 -4.63064C1.02516 -4.63064 0.439352 -4.02391 0.439352 -3.38232C0.439352 -3.02665 0.739228 -2.99178 0.808966 -2.99178C0.976339 -2.99178 1.17858 -3.11034 1.17858 -3.36139C1.17858 -3.48692 1.12976 -3.73101 0.767123 -3.73101C0.983313 -4.22615 1.45753 -4.37958 1.78531 -4.37958C2.48269 -4.37958 2.84533 -3.83562 2.84533 -3.27073C2.84533 -2.66401 2.41295 -2.18281 2.18979 -1.93176L0.509091 -0.27198C0.439352 -0.209215 0.439352 -0.195268 0.439352 0H3.31258L3.52179 -1.26924Z' id='g3-50'/>
</defs>
<g id='page1'>
<path d='M-36.9648 -35.9062C-36.9648 -40.582 -40.7578 -44.375 -45.4336 -44.375C-50.1094 -44.375 -53.9023 -40.582 -53.9023 -35.9062C-53.9023 -31.2266 -50.1094 -27.4375 -45.4336 -27.4375C-40.7578 -27.4375 -36.9648 -31.2266 -36.9648 -35.9062Z' fill='#80ff80'/>
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 -5.0817 29.7444)'>
<use x='-45.4333' xlink:href='#g0-120' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-39.7394' xlink:href='#g3-49' y='-62.7573'/>
</g>
<path d='M-36.9648 -7.5586C-36.9648 -12.2344 -40.7578 -16.0273 -45.4336 -16.0273C-50.1094 -16.0273 -53.9023 -12.2344 -53.9023 -7.5586C-53.9023 -2.8828 -50.1094 0.9102 -45.4336 0.9102C-40.7578 0.9102 -36.9648 -2.8828 -36.9648 -7.5586Z' fill='#80ff80'/>
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 -5.0817 58.0912)'>
<use x='-45.4333' xlink:href='#g0-120' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-39.7394' xlink:href='#g3-50' y='-62.7573'/>
</g>
<path d='M-36.9648 20.7891C-36.9648 16.1133 -40.7578 12.3203 -45.4336 12.3203C-50.1094 12.3203 -53.9023 16.1133 -53.9023 20.7891C-53.9023 25.4648 -50.1094 29.2578 -45.4336 29.2578C-40.7578 29.2578 -36.9648 25.4648 -36.9648 20.7891Z' fill='#80ff80'/>
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 -5.5585 86.438)'>
<use x='-45.4333' xlink:href='#g0-120' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-39.7394' xlink:href='#g1-110' y='-62.7573'/>
</g>
<path d='M33.9023 -7.5586C33.9023 -12.2344 30.1094 -16.0273 25.4336 -16.0273S16.9648 -12.2344 16.9648 -7.5586C16.9648 -2.8828 20.7578 0.9102 25.4336 0.9102S33.9023 -2.8828 33.9023 -7.5586Z' fill='#ff8080'/>
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 68.246 59.1843)'>
<use x='-44.7495' xlink:href='#g2-94' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-45.4333' xlink:href='#g0-121' y='-64.2516'/>
</g>
<path d='M-37.3867 -32.6875L16.0078 -11.3281' fill='none' stroke='#808080' stroke-miterlimit='10.0375' stroke-width='0.399994'/>
<path d='M15.4883 -13.2539C15.3594 -12.6601 16.0469 -11.4218 16.2852 -11.2187C15.9727 -11.2343 14.6211 -10.8086 14.3047 -10.2929' fill='none' stroke='#808080' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10.0375' stroke-width='0.319992'/>
<path d='M-36.7656 -7.5586H15.3125' fill='none' stroke='#808080' stroke-miterlimit='10.0375' stroke-width='0.400002'/>
<path d='M14.1172 -9.15234C14.2149 -8.55468 15.3125 -7.65625 15.6094 -7.55859C15.3125 -7.45703 14.2149 -6.5625 14.1172 -5.96484' fill='none' stroke='#808080' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10.0375' stroke-width='0.319985'/>
<path d='M-37.3867 17.5703L16.0078 -3.7891' fill='none' stroke='#808080' stroke-miterlimit='10.0375' stroke-width='0.399994'/>
<path d='M14.3047 -4.82422C14.6211 -4.30468 15.9727 -3.8789 16.2852 -3.89843C16.0469 -3.69531 15.3594 -2.45703 15.4883 -1.86328' fill='none' stroke='#808080' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10.0375' stroke-width='0.319992'/>
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 -19.9255 2.4907)'>
<use x='-40.0505' xlink:href='#g2-108' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-37.2831' xlink:href='#g2-97' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-32.5785' xlink:href='#g2-121' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-27.5972' xlink:href='#g2-101' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-23.1693' xlink:href='#g2-114' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-15.9468' xlink:href='#g2-48' y='-64.2516'/>
</g>
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 50.9415 2.4907)'>
<use x='-40.0505' xlink:href='#g2-108' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-37.2831' xlink:href='#g2-97' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-32.5785' xlink:href='#g2-121' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-27.5972' xlink:href='#g2-101' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-23.1693' xlink:href='#g2-114' y='-64.2516'/>
<use x='-15.9468' xlink:href='#g2-49' y='-64.2516'/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

And it has no text in it. Maybe is it because it's inside a TikZ picture? The fact is that is exactly this text that I want to convert.

Comment: If you call dvisvgm without option `-n`, it creates text rather than path elements. Only few browsers support them, though. So, the resulting SVGs might be rendered incorrectly.

Comment: @Martin I updated the question. As you can see I have no text tag. Also, I don't want to use strange character like integrals but only plain text and then use he font already loaded in my page to render it.

Comment: Did you try to call dvisvgm without option `-n` as mentioned above? That will create text elements rather than paths.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I misread your comment. Yes, I tried with success. Now I try to include it in my page and I'll post an edit if I encounter troubles (probably)

Comment: How would TikZ calculate the correct size of node shapes if it cannot render the node text? The shapes also cannot be resized with font size changes etc. I think that your diagram can be done only using some JavaScript diagram grawing library

Comment: @michal.h21 My idea - that could be wrong, of course - is that TikZ calculates the shapes of nodes based on the font it has in the .tex code. However, I could also include the font I use in the web-page in the .tex but the problem of having text exported as vectorial instad that as text with font still remain. And the text would be non-selectable.

Comment: @zyy I don't think that is a duplicate of that question. Mine is not simply how to export svg, but how to export it with text inside and display them in a web-page using the font of the web-page. However some answer are related to my problem.

Comment: @gvgramazio TikZ can calculate the correct node size, but only for the particular rendering of the text. The browser can render it differently, especially when different font sizes can be used. Also KaTeX can render math differently than LaTeX, so you may end with too small node shapes, with overflowing text. I think that best solution is to use the same font as you use on your page and export the outlines. You will loose the ability to change the font size and copy it, but it would look correctly in all browsers.

Comment: @michal.h21 You're more than probably right. I'm currently work on it to find the best solution. I think that I will go for use the same font of the web page in the .tex file and then export it with text tag and font option. I this way it should match as possible the page and also have selectable text.

Comment: The problem will be that if I change the font options in the web page I should somewhat manage to automatically change it in the .tex files and recompile it.

Comment: @gvgramazio You can add text within `tikzpicture` and the font could be adjusted to however you want.

Comment: @zyy What do you mean?

Comment: @gvgramazio You can try to use `\draw (0,0) node[below left=0.1cm and 0.03cm] {$R$};` to add text, be sure to include `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.

Comment: @zyy How is it different from what I currently have? What I wanted was to export an svg with text inside the tag "text". before they already suggest me to use `dvisvgm` and if I add `--font-format=woff` I have a better rendering.